# Need Ideas for Closing Panel from GridSplitter Column definition

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a requirement to show 3 panel with GridSplitter as separators in grid in WPF and C#. Also Closing options for each panel.

Plese see image to better understand design:

[image]

When user close the left panel , now the middle panel stretch from left , same-thing like right panel also. In run time i'll dock again these panels.

I'm tried to hidden/collapsed Closed panel and closed panel related splitterm but no luck.

Any suggestions or ideas would be most welcome?

**Edited** 
I required 5 column definitions including splitters  (3 panels and 2 splitters). Design code is

```
  <Grid Margin="0,120,0,20" Name="panelGrid">
        <!--
            1)Browser
            2)Player
            3)Chat
        -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Name="webBrowserPanel" Grid.Column="0" 
                   Visibility="Visible" Background="Green" Height="auto">
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="20" 
                    Height="20"  Click="leftBut"></Button>
        </DockPanel>

        <GridSplitter Name="sp1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" 
                      ShowsPreview="True" Width="5"/>

        <Grid x:Name="grid1" Grid.Column="2" AllowDrop="True" 
              Background="#FF807272"/>

        <GridSplitter Name="sp2" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" 
                      ShowsPreview="True" Width="5"/>

        <Grid x:Name="chatGrid" Grid.Column="4" Visibility="Visible"
              Background="DarkOrange" >
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="45" Height="20" 
                    Click="righCli">
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="leftColumn"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="rightColumn"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- u can also use DockPanel within a grid -->
    <DockPanel>
        <!-- this border is under the splitter and can't be seen-->
        <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="5"/>
        <Border Background="#AA0">
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_1" Content="x"/>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
    <Border Background="#0AA" Grid.Column="1">
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_2" Content="reset"/>
    </Border>
    <!-- u can also use grid within a grid -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- this is also an extra column for splitter -->
        <Border Background="Red" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Border Background="#A0A" Grid.Column="1">
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_3" Content="x"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" Width="5" x:Name="leftSplitter"/>
    <!-- by setting the correct margin you hide the underlying red border -->
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" x:Name="rightSplitter" Margin="0,0,-5,0"/>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    leftColumn.Width = new GridLength(0);
    leftSplitter.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    leftColumn.Width = new GridLength(40);
    rightColumn.Width = new GridLength(40);
    leftSplitter.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    rightSplitter.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}

private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rightColumn.Width = new GridLength(0);
    rightSplitter.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

it can improved using converters to bind splitters visibilities and columndefinitions widths to a property in view model.

Comment: you are rock.. Great answer .. i'm looking exact like this. Thanks

Comment: Thank you:) I've edited my answer a little see if the added parts give you more idea.